# Suppress / remove specific error in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Before I begin, I'd like to make clear that everything functions correctly. I know it may seem like I'm asking about things which aren't working, but it really is just incorrect error codes.

Anyway;

I'm using `std::thread` by means of an experimental MinGW, and unfortunately there seems to be a bug in that everything related to using `thread` throws the following:

`Type/Method "name" can not be resolved`

Now, the code is fine, builds fine and works fine so I'm certain it's just a bug with the errors. I'd like to know if there's a way to make these errors not appear when using `thread`. The catch is that I still want them to appear when I make a mistake elsewhere for other reasons.

Is there a way to suppress errors/warnings on a single line? Or a way to surround some code and ignore warnings on that code?

Oh, and I know this isn't a strictly programming question but as it's about a programming tool I think it's fine (I've seen enough questions like this, at least!).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do what I described above. The best I could find is blocking certain errors in certain files through the Eclipse code analysis menus. This isn't ideal though, because blocking something like `Method X can not be resolved` in an entire file could cause you to not see errors that come from areas of your code which you weren't expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse Oxygen.3 (or.2) markers can be suppressed by using "Quick Fix".
"Quick Fix" will add a comment like

```
// @suppress("Class members should be properly initialized")
```

but you can do it also manually.